# Efeito de toque (touch ripples) em toques e toques longos, com InkWell

Tags: flutter, dart

Podemos criar um botão com um `Container`, assim, deixá-lo como quisermos.

Minha dúvida, está no efeito de toque com o `InkWell`, que se adicionada uma cor ao `Container`, o mesmo "para de funcionar" como no exemplo:

[image: Exemplo]

Código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'InkWell Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(title: title),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(child: MyButton()),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // The InkWell wraps the custom flat button widget.
    return InkWell(
      // When the user taps the button, show a snackbar.
      onTap: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Tap'),
        ));
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Text('Flat Button'),
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Fonte: [ripples](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/ripples)

---

#### Dúvidas

- Como posso "corrigir" este problema?
- Quais outras alternativas de *widgets* para `buttom` customizado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como posso "corrigir" este problema?

Para fazer o que deseja, você precisa usar o Widget `Material` e setar a cor diretamente nele ao invés de colocar no `Container`, faça assim:

```
Material(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Tap'),
      ));
    },
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: Text('Flat Button'),
    ),
  )
);
```

**Explicação**

Esse "problema" ocorre porque o `Container` está "por cima" do `InkWell` e quando setada uma cor para ele, o mesmo deixa de ser transparente, assim então cobrindo os efeitos do `InkWell`

> Quais outras alternativas de widgets para buttons customizados?

Para criar seus botões customizados a utilização do `Container` é uma das melhores alternativas, pois o mesmo suporta diversas customizações, seria meio que um Widget "neutro".
Você pode utilizar também o `AnimatedContainer` que pode trazer uns efeitos bacana para suas customizações.

Comment: Uma das formas que testei foi exatamente essa! Achei aqui [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52697978/8745251). +1

Comment: Sim exatamente isso! Fazendo dessa forma você consegue os efeitos esperados

Comment: Mas usar Container para botões customizados ainda é o melhor!? Considerando uma padronização, efeitos, etc..

Comment: Resposta implementada, da uma olhada.